# MS Access: How to Make a Macro Generating Individualized Reports Work?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I currently have a macro in MS Access 2010 .mdb (Access 2002-'03 format).

The macro opens the Report and utilizes pairs of SetFilter and ExportWithFormatting. The macro hangs up after the first 2 or 3.

I was looking into placing delays but it appears that I would have to use VBA. Is that my only choice? Any suggestions or fixes to go about it?

```
Function Copy_Of_Wellness()
On Error GoTo Copy_Of_Wellness_Err

    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Wellness Plan Report", acViewReport, "", "", acIcon
    DoCmd.SetFilter "", "[Ind]=""Mary Jane""", ""
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Wellness Plan Report", 
           "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", """M:\Mary.pdf""", True, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.SetFilter "", "[Ind]=""Howard Johnson""", ""
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Wellness Plan Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", """M:\Howard.pdf""", True, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

Copy_Of_Wellness_Exit:
    Exit Function

Copy_Of_Wellness_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Copy_Of_Wellness_Exit

End Function
```

Despite what the initial error indicates, the report IS bounded and does produce the reports fine at first.

The stops are arbitrary, possibly run-time error?

[image: Reportedly Unbounded Report]

[image: Macro Stop]

Comment: Possibly show some code? It's hard to guess at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the *WhereCondition* in [DoCmd.OpenReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/docmd-openreport-method-access) and then passing an empty *ObjectName* argument in [DoCmdOutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/docmd-outputto-method-access) with no need for `DoCmd.SetFilter` as per the docs.

> ObjectName > Optional > Variant: ...If you want to output the active object, specify the object's type for the ObjectType argument and leave this argument blank...

**VBA**

Adjusted your use of quotes, also with remove of *acIcon* which may be hanging the processing as it launches an external taskbar action

```
...
DoCmd.OpenReport "Wellness Plan Report", acViewReport, , "[Ind]='Mary Jane'"       
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, "M:\Mary.pdf", True, , , acExportQualityPrint

DoCmd.OpenReport "Wellness Plan Report", acViewReport, , "[Ind]='Howard Johnson'"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, "M:\Howard.pdf", True, , , acExportQualityPrint
...
```

Even consider a loop for a DRY-er approach:

```
...
Dim var as Variant

For Each var in Array("Mary Jane", "Howard Johnson")
   DoCmd.OpenReport "Wellness Plan Report", acViewReport, , "[Ind]='" & var & "'",
   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, "M:\'" & var & "'.pdf", True, , , acExportQualityPrint
Next var
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty Fix:

1. `OpenReport()`
2. `SetFilter()`
3. `ExportWithFormatting()`
4. `CloseWindow()`

Rinse and repeat as necessary. Closing and reopening the Report was the only fix I could get working. `SelectObject()` and removing the filter with various commands proved ineffective.